# Is $1000000000000066600000000000001$ (Belphegor's prime) actually a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

There is a Wikipedia article about that evil [Belphegor's prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belphegor%27s_prime), but the references there seem relatively weak. Is this number actually a prime?

Comment: This is small enough that Wolfram can check it, it is prime.

Comment: [Yes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+1000000000000066600000000000001).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=isprime%5B1000000000000066600000000000001%5D

Comment: With `echo "isprime(1000000000000066600000000000001)" | gp`, the answer is `%1 = 1`.

Comment: Wolfram does a probable prime test, unless you have Mathematica with the PrimalityProving package and use ProvablePrimeQ.  Pari/GP's isprime(), as @egreg shows, does a proof (BLS75 or APR-CL).  You can also put it in http://sti15.com/nt/primality.cgi and get a BLS75 Theorem 5 proof with certificate for this number.

Comment: Mathematica gives a Pratt certificate: `{1000000000000066600000000000001, 3, {2, {5, 2, {2}}, {5365487, 
   5, {2, {7, 3, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {19, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {23, 
     5, {2, {11, 2, {2, {5, 2, {2}}}}}}, {877, 
     2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {73, 5, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}}}, {931881859, 
   2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {155313643, 
     2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {11, 2, {2, {5, 2, {2}}}}, {37, 
       2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}, {63601, 
       7, {2, {3, 2, {2}}, {5, 2, {2}}, {53, 
         2, {2, {13, 2, {2, {3, 2, {2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}`, in format explained at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110549/30771

Comment: Curiously it appears that  $1000000000000077700000000000001$ is also a prime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, Pari/GP offers a deterministic primality test (contrary to the probability test of Mathematica).

```
                            GP/PARI CALCULATOR Version 2.7.3 (released)
                    i386 running darwin (x86-64/GMP-6.0.0 kernel) 64-bit version
       compiled: May 24 2015, Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
                                      threading engine: single
                           (readline v6.3 enabled, extended help enabled)

                               Copyright (C) 2000-2015 The PARI Group

PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY 
WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?12 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 8000000, primelimit = 500000
? isprime(1000000000000066600000000000001)
%1 = 1
```

This is confirmed by http://sti15.com/nt/primality.cgi where, choosing “Proof”, we get

> Proving... output indicates progress. Certificate and timing at end.
>   $1000000000000066600000000000001$ is DEFINITELY PRIME.
>   Time taken: $0.523$ milliseconds.
>
> ```
> [MPU - Primality Certificate]
> Version 1.0
>
> Proof for:
> N 1000000000000066600000000000001
>
> Type BLS5
> N  1000000000000066600000000000001
> Q[1]  5
> A[0]  3
> ----
> ```

(Thanks to DanaJ for suggesting the site for the certificated primality test.)

Comment: What do `Q[1]` and `A[0]` mean?

Comment: @nbubis See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimalityCertificate.html

Comment: @nbubis https://github.com/danaj/Math-Prime-Util-GMP/blob/master/xt/proof-text-format.txt has a description, including reference to the paper.  The factors of N-1 used are 2 (implied as Q[0]) and 5.  With their multiplicity, that's enough to meet the requirements of the theorem.  A[0] says the 'a' value to use for the factor 2 in the theorem is 3 for this number.  There are verifiers in C and Perl that parse the text (they also handle Primo certificates).  Pari/GP has a way to show similar type (not format) certificates, and has an excellent APR-CL system, but it has no certs.

Answer (score 5):

Both Mathematica and WolframAlfa confirm that this number is prime:

```
In[42]:= PrimeQ[1000000000000066600000000000001]

Out[42]= True
```

Comment: PrimeQ is a probable prime test.  Pari/GP's isprime() does a proof.

Comment: @DanaJ Not entirely true: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132670/some-information-about-primeq-function?rq=1

Comment: @Klangen, there is a primality proving package for Mathematica though the documentation says it uses a different function ProvablePrimeQ[].  I don't believe Wolfram Alpha supports this at all (certainly not in the free version).  So in reference to ahkaissi's answer that PrimeQ confirm the number this size is prime, I believe my statement is true.